# Is determinism an emergent property of non-deterministic systems?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, emergent-properties

In a similar way to how irreversible macroscopic processes are emergent from reversible microscopic processes, are deterministic macroscopic processes emergent from non-deterministic microscopic processes? And analogous to how statistical mechanics allows us to work out the relationship between micro and macro states, is there a discipline which looks at how indeterminism gives rise to determinism?

Comment: [Central limit theorem?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)[The law of large numbers?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)